# cell becomes non-responsive when kernel is busy(connected)

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-lab, bert-language-model

I have been trying to run BERTopic for 5MB text data. Once I run the codes, the below code's cell doesn't give a response, no error. and the codes below also doesn't run because the notebook behaves like there is an issue there and the rest of the code doesn't run.

The code works without issue on Colab, however, due to ram issues on collab I need to run the code at JupyterLab on my local machine, which is MacProM1.

```
from bertopic import BERTopic 
topic_model = BERTopic(embedding_model='bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
topics,_= topic_model.fit_transform(sentences)
```

Once I run the below code, the cell becomes irresponsive without any error, while the kernel is still connected.
As a solution to this,

1. I tried to move all codes to a new notebook at JupyterLab but it didn't solve as well.
2. I uninstalled and then again installed all the packages needed for this project, but still no solution.
3. I also tried `!pip install --upgrade ipykernel` and it did not work as well.
   [how the cell looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWf3I.png)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, cells in Jupyter notebooks could become non-responsive for [many reasons](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11027#issuecomment-406794331). So I would start by looking here for proper debugging.

Thus said, the same happens to me when loading Bert based models in my experimental environment while running many other things on the laptop. Most of the pre-trained models are rather huge and occupy space in memory when loaded. If there isn't enough space to hold the model the notebook would just go to that blank state and you would have to rerun everything from the top.

Here's an example of how much memory is used when importing SBERT and loading your model:

```
%%memit
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
```

Output: `peak memory: 264.45 MiB, increment: 216.70 MiB`

```
%%memit
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
```

Output: `peak memory: 1103.46 MiB, increment: 838.79 MiB`

This is telling me that these two lines used up to 1GB of the available memory. I would start by looking at your memory usage.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud; thank you for your help and message.
sentence transformers: peak memory: 1315.89 MiB, increment: 335.47 MiB
bert base nli: peak memory: 1308.78 MiB, increment: -14.73 MiB
 is that mean, I have a memory issue here? my macbook is 16 gb... I am suprised actually

Comment: Your code fails when running the code anyway, so I wouldn't rely on the memit output at this stage. It was just to give you an idea. In your case, the model isn't actually loaded (hence no increment in memory when calling for the loading). Please check what else is running in your environment and then debugs based on the other issues referred on my link.